# Differentiate between field on background page and on form through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms

I need to differentiate between two fields (named ABC) through JavaScript. 
I have a main page and the field ABC appears on that, and then i have a form (new content added dialogue) which appers on top of that main page. Now the form also has the field ABC as well.

I want to do something with the field on the form, but the javaScipt keeps picking up the field on the background page.

Please anyone who could help?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there something I could do/add which would make a restriction on only to pick the field on the form?

Comment: Add some code of what you were trying. What do you use ?
plain javascript ? jquery ?

Comment: please recreate the code here, so we can help you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Add a data attribute to either the field or the form.

**HTML**

```
<form data-which-form="main">
  <input type="text"name="abc">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<form data-which-form="popup">
  <input type="text"name="abc">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('submit','form',function(e){
  if($(this).data('which-form')=='main'){
   var mainAbc = $(this).find('input[name=abc]');
  }
  //do stuff
});
```